# How to suppress dialog boxes coming from submitted program

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I'm submitting a Z** program which is copy of the standard report of SAP (FBL5N). But there is a message saying that;

> (count)  archived documents were found

which is coming out from the logical database FBL5N uses. But I have to suppress this dialog box. I don't want is to be shown to user. (I shoudln't submit it as background job because I have to import the results from the FBL5N report).

I've tried

```
CALL FUNCTION 'DIALOG_SET_NO_DIALOG'
SUPPRESS DIALOG
```

etc.

Here is my submit;

```
  SUBMIT /xyz/blablabla WITH so_wlbuk IN s_bukrs
                        WITH so_wlkun IN s_kunnr
                        WITH so_datex IN s_datex
                        WITH x_opsel  = x_opsel
                        WITH pa_stida = pa_stida
                        WITH x_clsel  = x_clsel
                        WITH pa_stid2 = pa_stid2
                        WITH x_aisel  = x_aisel
                        WITH so_budat IN s_budat
                        WITH so_bldat IN s_bldat
                        WITH x_norm   = x_norm
                        WITH x_shbv   = x_shbv
                        WITH x_ters   = x_ters
                        WITH x_denk   = x_denk
                        WITH dd_bukrs IN s_bukrs
                        WITH x_apar = p_c_apar 
                        WITH dd_kunnr IN s_kunnr
                        WITH so_konzs IN s_ckonzs
                        WITH s_umskz IN s_umskz
                        WITH s_blart IN s_blart
                        WITH so_gsber IN s_gsber
                        AND RETURN.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Give us the **full** code with which you call the FBL5N transaction.

Comment: I put the submit code. Just a normal submit. @Suncatcher

Comment: There is no such report in the standard system, it seems to be IS, or partner's extension or whatever.

Comment: But if we are speaking particularly about **FBL5N** (report `RFITEMAR`) as it was stated in your question, it returns reesult list wonderfully without any prompts or messages. Either is is launched by `SUBMIT`, or by `CALL TRANSACTION`, it doesn't matter.

Comment: It is copy of the standart program FBL5N. Yes FBL5N returns a warning message "[count of documents] archived documents were found" if you have archived documents. So I need to suppress this message without editing the submitted program.

Comment: Maybe you can use BAPI_AR_ACC_GETOPENITEMS to achieve what you want. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the code of this report and yes, the message is thrown both in GUI mode and when calling programmatically.
This LDB message is called deeply in standard code and cannot be suppressed (`GD_COUNT_ARCH` variable in SAPDBDDF report is checked).

The only solution I see here is calling transaction in batch mode. You ambiguously said you should (shouldn't?) do this in background, but nevertheless, BDC display mode is adjustable and if you want to avoid deep modifications of standard, this is your only solution.

The call can be organized just like that:

```
SET PARAMETER ID 'KUN' FIELD '1174'.

DATA: it_bdcdata TYPE TABLE OF bdcdata,
      wa_bdcdata LIKE LINE OF it_bdcdata,
      opt TYPE ctu_params.

      CLEAR: wa_bdcdata.
      wa_bdcdata-PROGRAM = 'RFITEMAR'.
      wa_bdcdata-DYNPRO = '1000'.
      wa_bdcdata-DYNBEGIN = 'X'.
      APPEND wa_bdcdata TO it_bdcdata.

      CLEAR: wa_bdcdata.
      wa_bdcdata-fnam = 'X_AISEL'.
      wa_bdcdata-fval = 'X'.
      APPEND wa_bdcdata TO it_bdcdata.

      CLEAR: wa_bdcdata.
      wa_bdcdata-fnam = 'BDC_OKCODE'.
      wa_bdcdata-fval = '=ONLI'.
      APPEND wa_bdcdata TO it_bdcdata.

      opt-dismode = 'E'.

CALL TRANSACTION 'FBL5N' USING it_bdcdata OPTIONS FROM opt.
```

Only one parameter was filled here (**All items** radiobutton in **Line item selection** section) and you can fill missing ones according this sample. I recommend you to use [SPA/GPA](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/9f/db9e0435c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm) parameteres for initial entry where possible as this is more compact and works faster than BDC table.